# Boot extremely slow after triple boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot

Recently, I added Kali to my dual boot Win10/Ubuntu 16.04.
Ever since, the startup time of my Ubuntu became extremely long.
I have no idea what caused this...
In the meantime, Kali has been deleted again, but the boot time stays the same.
Below, I've added the output of dmesg.

Thanks.

[dmesg output](https://pastebin.com/hAtRuQC3)

Comment: UEFI or BIOS (Legacy/CSM)? Who's in charge of Grub, Ubuntu or Kali?

Comment: Looks like an issue with wifi, try disabling/enabling it.

Comment: When you installed Kali, did it recreate swap which gave it new UUID. Or do UUID of swap in `cat /etc/fstab` not match UUID from `sudo blkid -c /dev/null -o list`

Comment: @oldfred, these IDs do indeed not match, can I just change the fstab file or?

Comment: @Artyom, enabling or disabling the wifi didnt change anything unfortunately

Comment: @MichaelBay, I think UEFI and Ubuntu... Is there a way to make sure?

Comment: You can edit fstab with correct UUID and then run this to make sure it is correct. IF not errors then ok. `sudo mount -a`. Query to see if UEFI or BIOS `
[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "EFI boot on HDD" || echo "Legacy boot on HDD" `

Comment: Just to be clear the regression is from making the swap not the wifi. Nor would booting as legacy vs UEFI cause this.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion of oldfred improved my boot time drastically: I had to change the UUID in `/etc/fstab` so it matched the one in `blkid`